# Wildfly, spring data jpa get NoClassDefFoundError: HibernateException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, wildfly

Hi I am trying to create a spring mvc application on wildfly 9 with spring data jpa, when I add in the jpa related config and dependencies, it gets NoClassDef Found error. Here's the server log:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:60)

Maven pom:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>testspringmvc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
          <artifactId>wildfly-parent</artifactId>
          <version>9.0.1.Final</version>
          <type>pom</type>
          <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
          <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.23</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The config class

```
package com;

//import skipped...

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com*")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TestAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.freeMarker().cache(false);
    }

    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer() throws TemplateException, IOException {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        configurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/freemarker/");
        return configurer;
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractPlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        bean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter()); //This is the line the log complaining
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");

        bean.setJpaProperties(props);
        return bean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("java:/PostgresDS");
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Did i do anything wrong?

For maven, i read somewhere that using jpa should not include hibernate-core but the HibernateException is in there, but include and exclude it gives the same error.

Project ran on wildfly 9 using eclipse and wildfly plugin.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put provided scope for jpa 2.1 api, and exclude the same api from hibernate core for it to work.